# Why I am not able to create an image from docker file?

Tags: docker, visual-studio

I try to create an image from the docker file.
I have a .NET CORE 5 solution that contains 4 projects.

The Web project has references to all other projects:

[image]

I used a visual studio tool to create a docker file.

This a docker file which is created by visual studio:

```
 #See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

#Depending on the operating system of the host machines(s) that will build or run the containers, the image specified in the FROM statement may need to be changed.
#For more information, please see https://aka.ms/containercompat

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["PhoneNumberValidator.Web/PhoneNumberValidator.Web.csproj", "PhoneNumberValidator.Web/"]
COPY ["PhoneNumberValidator.Entities/PhoneNumberValidator.Entities.csproj", "PhoneNumberValidator.Entities/"]
COPY ["PhoneNumberValidator.DAL/PhoneNumberValidator.DAL.csproj", "PhoneNumberValidator.DAL/"]
COPY ["PhoneNumberValidator.Application/PhoneNumberValidator.Application.csproj", "PhoneNumberValidator.Application/"]
RUN dotnet restore "PhoneNumberValidator.Web/PhoneNumberValidator.Web.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/PhoneNumberValidator.Web"
RUN dotnet build "PhoneNumberValidator.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "PhoneNumberValidator.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "PhoneNumberValidator.Web.dll"]
```

I run this command in the folder where Dockerfile is located to create the image:

docker build -t pnvimage .

And here is what I get when I try to build a docker file:

[image]

As you can see it says:

`failed to compute cache key "/PhoneNumberValidator.Application/PhoneNumberValidator.Application.csproj" not found: not found`

But csproj file exists in PhoneNumberValidator.Application project.

On your opinion what may be the issue with building the image from Dockerfile?

**UPDATE:**
Here is a tree of my project structure:

```
PhoneNumberValidator/
├── PhoneNumberValidator.Web/
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── PhoneNumberValidator.Web.csproj
│   └── ...
├── PhoneNumberValidator.Entities/
│   ├── PhoneNumberValidator.Entities.csproj
│   └── ...
├── PhoneNumberValidator.DAL/
│   ├── PhoneNumberValidator.DAL.csproj
│   └── ...
├── PhoneNumberValidator.Application/
│   ├── PhoneNumberValidator.Application.csproj
│   └── ...
└── ...
```

Comment: Notice the path where you are running `docker build` from. It is inside `PhoneNumberValidator.Web` folder. If you want your dockerfile to work, then this folder has to have those other 4 subfolders that it is looking for. If you think that's not the issue you should add the tree of your project structure to your question.

Comment: @markhc I added a tree of the project structure.
Could you please review it?

Comment: @markhc, the point that the docker file was created by Visual Studio, in the Web project,
and when it is built from Visual Studio it creates an image, while I try to run using this command: "docker build -t pnvimage ." from cmd it fails.
I do not understand why it happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occurs because the command context doesn't contain necessary files. You need to call the command from the directory with solution file. To specify the Dockerfile use `-f` option:

```bash
docker build -f PhoneNumberValidator.Web/Dockerfile -t pnvimage .
```

Answer (score 0):

Already mentioned by @markhc you are running `docker build` command in the wrong directory (`PhoneNumberValidator/PhoneNumberValidator.Web/`.

You have to execute it in `PhoneNumberValidator/`

If running `docker build -t yourtag .` the `.` specifies that for the build command the current working directory is the root directory, meaning docker build cannot access/see any other files outside this directory. Thus, to make `PhoneNumberValidator.Entities`, `PhoneNumberValidator.DAL`, ... visible in the contect of your build you have to run the command in the parent directory of these folders, namely `PhoneNumberValidator`.

This is also the place where the Dockerfile should reside, imho (but that's not mandatory).

---

Additionally, if you do not split the build stage any further, the last copy makes the first 4 copies already obsolete.

```
COPY ["PhoneNumberValidator.Web/PhoneNumberValidator.Web.csproj", "PhoneNumberValidator.Web/"]
COPY ["PhoneNumberValidator.Entities/PhoneNumberValidator.Entities.csproj", "PhoneNumberValidator.Entities/"]
COPY ["PhoneNumberValidator.DAL/PhoneNumberValidator.DAL.csproj", "PhoneNumberValidator.DAL/"]
COPY ["PhoneNumberValidator.Application/PhoneNumberValidator.Application.csproj", "PhoneNumberValidator.Application/"]
RUN dotnet restore "PhoneNumberValidator.Web/PhoneNumberValidator.Web.csproj"
COPY . .
```